# Enhanced loop not summing values properly

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to sum all of the digits in a array with a `for loop` and a `enhanced loop`. The `for loop` is working fine but the `enhanced loop` is returning an `out of bounds error`.

Follows the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{     
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
     //This code sums all of the values in an array with a for loop

     int count = 0;

     int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};        

     for(int item = 0; item<array.length; item++)
        {
           count += array[item];
        }

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array) + "\nCount = " + count);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //This code is supposed to sum all of the digits in an array with a enhanced loop 
      int count2 = 0;

     int[] array2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};        

     for(int item : array2)
        {
           count2 += array2[item];
        }

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2) + "\nCount = " + count2);            
  }
}
```

Comment: In java, `item` represent the value, this is not like javascript where `item` would represent the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enhanced loop doesn't count the indexing- it extracts the item itself. So all you need is:

```
for(int item: array2){
  count2 += item;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for responding @SarTheFirst. Your code worked. Nobody in my AP Computer Science class knew the answer.